# resumeChunkSize option

Tags: angularjs, ng-file-upload

I tried to use the resumeChunkSize option. For example,

```
Upload.upload({
    url: 'myurl',
    data: {
        file: file
    }
    ,resumeChunkSize: '10MB'
```

Found out that this causes ng-file-upload to repeatedly upload the same chunk even if the file is smaller than the chunk. What is the correct server response to prevent this or is this a bug?
This is easily reproduced by taking the fiddle 'Drop and upload' and adding the above resumeChunkSize option to it

Comment: You can try it on the demo page, setting it to 10MB works fine.

Comment: You need to provide `resumeSizeUrl` so the client know how much of the file is being uploaded to resume from there. If it is not provided client thinks nothing is uploaded on the server hence trying to upload it again and again for the same chunk.

Comment: Or you can provide a `resumeSize` function option that returns how much of the file is uploaded so far.